# Listening to Akka-HTTP ports remotely

Tags: scala, akka, port, akka-http

When binding calls to port 9000 with Akka-HTTP

```
Http().bindAndHandle(routes, "localhost", 9000)
```

It starts listening to the port as seen with 'netstat -tulpn'

```
Proto  Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address   Foreign Address  State   
tcp6   0       0       127.0.0.1:9000  :::*             LISTEN
```

Locally this port can be used. **However**, when I make a remote call I get:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 169.254.0.2 port 9000: Connection refused
```

Even though pinging is possible and the devices are directly connected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Replace `localhost` with `0.0.0.0` and it will work. `localhost` is intended to be used only locally.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind to the IP address:

```
Http().bindAndHandle(routes, "169.254.0.2", 9000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Listening only localhost interface is a good practice. In production use you should catch request from public interfaces via proxy (nginx or apache)